# Is there a Pip command to check which python version a package needs?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade, versioning

I need to compile a list of packages I've installed that will no longer work with the upgrade from python 3.9 to 3.10. I'm guessing I'll need a pip command to check which python version the package requires. I know you can do this manually but I am looking for a pip command.

If there isn't one, is there some sort of standard way to check which packages will not work when you upgrade your python version without just cold upgrading and seeing what breaks?

Comment: I'm afraid upgrading and seeing what breaks is the only way.

Comment: actually, any Python project you have there would better be in a private "virtualenv": that way each project will have their own dependencies, in the appropriate versions, and Python interpreter./ Updating a system-wide Python that is used across many projects is just asking to break everything. 

Look at "pyenv" to learn how to have several Python versions installed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

To see the list of installed packages:

pip3 list

To see outdated packages:

pip3 list -o or --outdated

To upgrade a package:

pip3 install --upgrade <package_name>

Comment: This is helpful, but I am actually looking to see if there is a command to check which versions of python each package is compatible with.